# Asp.net identity - How to maintain logged in user role?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-identity, identity

I m using Angularjs project and using Asp.net identity custom storage provider with Enterprise library for token authentication.

Implemented custom userstore to create an account.

**[Authorize]** attribute works well after logged in. i want to restrict the method for particular user.

So tried to implement **[Authorize(Roles="Admin,User")]**.

Here one user can have two roles in practical. But as per the system, when user login, we restrict the user to select the particular role.

So, after validated by asp.net identity, user should select any one of the role.

Here my need is,

I want to maintain the role which he selected (we consider this concept like impersonate user, but not exactly).

Or,

Need to implement in the Authorize attribute itself.

I've seen some of the examples like we can add claim to identity.

But I can add custom claims only inside the method,

**GenerateUserIdentityAsync**

in my case I need to add claim after log in validated. I've gone through some example and implemented like following.

```
 ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Test"));
```

After added claim, when I try to get the claim to check the logged in user role,

```
 List<Claim> claim = claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
```

I didn't get the **Role "Test"**.

Here my bad luck is, in claims, I've all the roles of the user **except role = test**

How to authorize the user role or maintain logged in here..

Comment: Can you mention the reason for down vote?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can make perfect use of the claim based authentication mechanisms here.

Comment: Actually I did authorize based on the role. But sometime user has more than one role. I want to allow user with the one role to the system. He will be asked to select the role before enter into the application. In that case, I need the solution for that.

Comment: I've added current user role in the like userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Jeeva"));. I could get that detail in the methods. Is that ok to validate in the web api actions to know the current logged in user role?

Comment: Is there any tutorial to implement impersonate in asp.net web api with identity?

Comment: Restricting a user to one role is not "impersonation".
Do you use OWIN? Then take a Middleware to remove the Claims, which are too much: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/09/18/claims-transformation-middleware-for-katana/

Comment: Thanks about impersonation and thanks for your good suggestions. To remove claims if not a good idea, is there any other option to maintain the data? Now I am planned to use session for this one, since my project wont expose to other application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least three solutions for your problem:

1. Use a claim transformation to filter the role claims, to match a role the user choose. You can use a claim transformation middleware or you can filter the claims during login (be aware, that you do not know the user roles BEFORE login, and afterwards filtering might be too late). **PRO** Does not necessarily need session state; **CON** User can not choose during runtime.
2. Store the role in the session and authenticate against that role. Make sure, that you check against the role claims, when the user chooses his role. **PRO** User might change role without re-sign-in. **CON** Needs session state (Might be an issue in farm environments).
3. **Don't do it at all** and I'm totally serious about that. Provide your user a clean interface, that makes him know, what role he has and use areas and other technics to separate the concerns.